# Virtual PC, bigger resolution

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, high-resolution

I have a virtual machine (Virtual PC) and I want to set a bigger resolution than my monitor/videocard allows. Thats because I want to stream a "scrollable" game, and if I could increment the resolution, I wont need to scroll during the game (it summary will be shrinked, of course).

How to do this?

Comment: what guest OS? It might help to state this

Comment: Windows XP SP 3

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the full resolution on a virtual machine you'll need to install [Virtual PC Additions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824561/en-us).

To do this you'll need to do the following

[image]

1. While you are running one of your virtual machines, click on Action
2. Then click on Install or Update Virtual Machine Additions (or hit Right Alt + I)

[image]

3 . You will be prompted with the window above which states that a CD image will be inserted in the Virtual Drive, the CD-ROM contains the installation files for the Virtual Machine Additions. Click Continue so that the virtual CD-ROM is loaded.

From there just continue installation and you'll be able to take advantage of the full screen.

Comment: thx for the comment, but I didnt mean the full screen :) I still cant set very high resolution.